# How to Use Material Design Lite in a React Native Application

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, material-design-lite

I was wondering if there is an easy way to use Google's Material Design Lite (https://getmdl.io) with a React native application. The problem is: React Native styles the application using JavaScript and style names are written using camel casing instead of the regular web style kebab case.

Answer (score 1):

I use Native Base. 
Very similar, I don't think you'll be able to directly use Material Design with RN.

https://nativebase.io/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have **a couple options**. First is to use [React Native Material Kit](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit), which is what I would recommend. You can customize it with a Material Design Lite theme.

The other option would be to convert Material CSS to Javascript objects using a converter like [Native CSS](https://github.com/raphamorim/native-css) and import it into your project (could be painful).